# added button programmatically to layout, but not appearing

Tags: android

Looking at various examples, below is what seems to be the correct way of adding a view to a layout. However, nothing shows up for me. I'm assuming it has something to do with the layout options, but I'm new so I don't know what is missing.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.songs_layout);
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.songs_layout, null);

            Button myButton = new Button(this);
            myButton.setText("Change View");
            myButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            layout.addView(myButton);


        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `layout` variable is not the same as the layout you used in `setContentView`. Try calling `setContentView(layout);` after `layout.addView(myButton);` and removing the previous call to it (`setContentView(R.layout.songs_layout);`).

To be more clear, your onCreate method should look like

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.songs_layout, null);

    Button myButton = new Button(this);
    myButton.setText("Change View");
    myButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.addView(myButton);
    setContentView(layout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the button to the layout that's displayed.  You're inflating a new layout and adding the button to that one.  Move `setContentView()` to after `layout.addView(myButton)`, then change it to `setContentView(layout)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for Fragment context with Kotlin:**
In `Fragment` where the view is inflated in `onCreateView` the solution is a bit different. The inflated layout is returned:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment()
    {
    lateinit var v: View

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                          container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false)
        // ...
        return v
    }
}
```

In this case, it might be confusing that fetching the parent of the buttons with `findViewById` and adding the buttons to this view would not work:

```
val buttonsParent = v.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.buttons_parent)
buttonsParent.addView(myButton)
```

Instead what you need to do is add the buttons directly with following syntax:

```
v.buttons_parent.addView(myButton)
```